We throw a die 900 times. What is the probability that the frequency of occurrence of an even number is between $0.50$ and $0.55$?
Question :
We throw a die $n=900$ times. What is the probability that the frequency of occurrence of an even number is between $0.50$ and $0.55$?

Attempt:
I think I have to use a normal distribution to solve this.
However, I'm not given any normal distribution. Can I assume that the mean of such a normal distribution is $0.50$ (because the
random variable $X$ defined as the frequency of occurrence of an even number in $n=900$ throws follows a Bernoulli distribution? (Where $ $ $E(X)=900/2=450$ $ $ $ $ and $ $ $ $ $\sigma (X)= 15$.)
In proportions of $n$, this gives $ $ $ $ $E(X)/900=0.5$ $ $ $ $ and $ $ $ $ $\sigma (X)/900=1/60$.
But
$3 \sigma (X)/900 = 0.05$
So, I can now use the Empirical Rule to find the answer.

If this is correct, then I'm not sure why I'm allowed to jump from the Bernoulli distribution above to the normal distribution defined with it. Why would that be allowed?

You might as well toss a coin instead of throwing a die...

Central Limit Theorem tells you the process converges (in probability) to the normal as the number of tosses gets large.  Note that you'll want to use the continuity correction (to account for the fact that the number of good tosses must be an integer) and note too that it isn't all that hard to do it exactly with the Binomial process (using a machine of course).  Worth comparing the answers.

@TonyK I guess. I didn't come up with the question.

Each individual throw follows a Bernoulli distribution, but the number of counts over $n = 900$ throws follows a binomial distribution. There is an exact answer to your question, but if you want to approximate it, you can use that the binomial distribution for large $n$ is approximated by a normal distribution, in your problem with mean 450 and standard deviation 225.

@doetoe  typo:  you meant Variance $= 225$.

@lulu That's right, thank you!

The statistic of interest is the frequency or proportion of rolls that are even; i.e., if $X$ is the random number of even die rolls in $n = 900$ trials, we want to know $$\Pr\left[0.50 \le \frac{X}{900} \le 0.55\right]. \tag{1}$$
As such, we can proceed by considering the proportion $X/900$ directly, or we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$\Pr[450 \le X \le 495]. \tag{2}$$
Using a normal approximation to the binomial will work in either case, but the parameters will be different depending on whether you want to work with $X$ or $X/900$.  The general idea is to select the parameters so that the mean and variance match the respective mean and variance of the statistic of interest.
Let's do this for $(1)$.  The variable $X$ is binomial with parameters $n = 900$ and $p = \frac{1}{2}$, because the probability that any single die roll is even is $3/6 = 1/2$.  So we have
$$\mu = \operatorname{E}[X/900] = \frac{np}{n} = p = \frac{1}{2}, \\
\sigma^2 = \operatorname{Var}[X/900] = \frac{np(1-p)}{n^2} = \frac{p(1-p)}{n} = \frac{1}{3600}. \tag{3}$$
Thus $X/900$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $\mu = 1/2$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 1/3600$.  Then $$Z = \frac{X/900 - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{X/900 - 1/2}{1/60} \tag{4}$$
is approximately normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$.
Now we use this to calculate the desired probability:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[0.50 \le \frac{X}{900} \le 0.55\right] &= \Pr\left[\frac{0.50 - 1/2}{1/60} \le \frac{X/900 - 1/2}{1/60} \le \frac{0.55 - 1/2}{1/60}\right] \\
&\approx \Pr[0 \le Z \le 3]. \end{align} \tag{5}$$
The approximate probability is then calculated using the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution:
$$\Pr[0 \le Z \le 3] = \Phi(3) - \Phi(0) \approx 0.99865 - 0.5 = 0.49865. \tag{6}$$
However, the exact probability should be $0.512094\ldots$.  What went wrong?  The reason the approximation is poor is because we did not employ continuity correction.  When approximating a discrete distribution with a continuous one, we must consider that at the boundary of the probability interval, we must include or exclude the entirety of the probability mass at that boundary.  In this case, we wanted $\Pr[0.50 \color{red}{\le} X/900 \color{red}{\le} 0.55]$, meaning that we need to include the entire probability masses at $X/900 = 0.50$ (equivalently, $X = 450$), and $X/900 = 0.55$ (equivalently, $X = 495$).  Note that
$$\Pr[X = 450] = \binom{900}{450}(1/2)^{450}(1 - 1/2)^{900 - 450} = 0.0265888\ldots. \tag{7}$$
This means our uncorrected normal approximation is going to incorrectly exclude about half of this probability mass, or $0.0132944$, a substantial amount.  The continuity corrected computation is easier to see if we work with $(2)$:
$$\Pr[450 \le X \le 495] = \Pr[449.5 \le X \le 495.5]. \tag{8}$$  The reason for subtracting $0.5$ from $450$ and adding $0.5$ to $495$ is that we want to include the entirety of the discrete probability masses at $X = 450$ and $X = 495$.
Then if we want to reuse our work from $(1)$, we again divide by $900$ to obtain
$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[\frac{449.5}{900} \le \frac{X}{900} \le \frac{495.5}{900}\right] &= \Pr\left[-\frac{1}{30} \le \frac{X/900 - 1/2}{1/60} \le \frac{91}{30}\right] \\
&= \Pr\left[-\frac{1}{30} \le Z \le \frac{91}{30}\right]. \end{align} \tag{9}$$
Then we compute
$$\Phi(91/30) - \Phi(-1/30) \approx 0.998791 - 0.486704 = 0.512086. \tag{10}$$
We have reduced the error to about $0.000008$, whereas the uncorrected probability has error of about $0.013$.  The overwhelming portion of this error comes from the endpoint $X = 450$, because the probability mass at the other endpoint $X = 495$ is relatively tiny:
$$\Pr[X = 495] = \binom{900}{495} (1/2)^{495} (1 - 1/2)^{900 - 495} = 0.000294634\ldots, \tag{11}$$
which is about $90$ times smaller than the mass at $X = 450$.  Nevertheless, if one is to use continuity correction, it should be used at all relevant boundary points.
